# Cannot expose docker app on server to external IP

Tags: docker, dockerfile, iptables

I'm trying to make [this CNIL/PIA](https://github.com/LINCnil/pia) app available on my server using a docker container. However, I cannot seem to be able to correctly bind the ports of my machine and my container.

My Dockerfile is

```
from node

maintainer Théophile Dano <theophile@fifty-five.com>

run mkdir -p /app
run chown node:node /app

workdir /app

copy . /app

user node

expose 4200

run npm i 

cmd ["./node_modules/.bin/ng", "server"]
```

And the command to start the container I use is:

```
docker run -i -t -P MY_SERVER_IP::4200 cnil-pia
```

In my IP tables I have (`sudo iptables -t nat -L -n`):

```
Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            MY_SERVER_IP        tcp dpt:32768 to:172.17.0.2:4200
```

However, the app is not available when I try to access MY_SERVER_IP:4200 in my browser.

Any insights on what I am doing wrong ? or not doing at all ?

Comment: Does this work `docker run -it -p 4200:4200 cnil-pia`?

Comment: No it doesn"t :/

Comment: Are you running on windows? or any virtual machine?

Comment: `Linux 32~14.04.1-Ubuntu x86_64` server in OVH

Comment: And my firewall is disabled

Comment: OVH i assume you are talking about virtual machine, make sure you start your VM on bridge adapter and not on NAT address. If this is not the case please ignore.

Answer (score 1):

You use `-P` key in your `docker run` statement which means:

> -P, --publish-all                           Publish all exposed ports to random ports

You need to use `-p` which is:

> -p, --publish list                          Publish a container's port(s) to the host (default [])

Also you need to specify your host's port as well.

So, finally it is:

```
docker run -it -p MY_SERVER_IP:4200:4200 cnil-pia
```

p.s. And maybe you need to run your container in background, so it is:

```
docker run -d -p MY_SERVER_IP:4200:4200 cnil-pia
```

Comment: The documentation states that `IP:!:port` is equivalent to `IP:host_port:container_port`. Plus, this is the command I used before posting there :)

Comment: Yes, but key should be not capital `-P`, it should be `-p`. https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/

Comment: Yup, same issue

Comment: Is container running after `docker run`?

Comment: Yes it is, I actually don't run it in background so I can see the logs, its works fin and serves properly

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, it seems that docker doesn't expose the `127.0.0.1` (aka `localhost`) ports but rather the `0.0.0.0` ones. Making Angular serve on the latter made the whole thing work !

`ng serve --host 0.0.0.0`